# Linq Select Expression this keyword

Tags: c#, linq

In select clause is it possible to point an other level object in select clause or is there any special keyword to point. If not how can I solve this with select clause.

```
list.Select(o => new ParentClass {
   ID = o.ID,                            
   ChildClass = o.Childs.Select(p => new ChildClass { 
                                     Parent = @this,
                                     ID = p.id 
                               }).ToList()
});
```

Comment: But `o` is anonymous object

Comment: This is list     ` o =>
                        new
                        {
                            o.ID,                            
                            Childs = o.Childs.Select(p => new { p.ID })

                        })`

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework entities and want to fetch them with related objects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you cannot. Because `ParentClass` instance is not yet created. You need something like the following.

```
list.Select(o =>
{ 
   var parent = new ParentClass
    {
        ID = o.ID
    };
    parent.ChildClass = o.Childs
                        .Select(p =>
                           new ChildClass 
                           { 
                               Parent = parent,
                               ID = p.id 
                           })
                         .ToList();
     return parent;
});
```

Comment: What about in Entity framework is it possible to select this way.

Comment: @Horizon Am sorry, I can't answer this question. Am not an expert in that topic :(

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this using object initializer.

```
list.Select(o => 
    {
        var pc = new ParentClass();
        pc.ID = o.ID;
        pc.ChildClass = o.Childs.Select(p => new ChildClass 
            { 
                Parent = pc,
                ID = p.id 
            }).ToList();
        return pc;
    });
```